# Why isn't my Flutter app on the list of apps to open txt file?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I want to open a txt file with my flutter app .It's like when i tap on txt file i would like to see my flutter app as recommend apps to open with but i have no idea how to do that
Please give some Idea

Comment: could you share your code/implementation? Apps don't show as recommended just "because". You need to specify that your app has that capability and a logic for it.

Comment: There are two things you gotta do in windows, first, understand that opening a file is equivalent as running the application and passing the path to the file as a command-line argument, so make sure your app understands how to open the file from the command line. Second, right-click on a text file and: open with -> other app -> always open this type of file with this app -> more apps -> pick an app from system -> navigate to your .exe file and select it.

Comment: @Mariano Zorrilla i don't have any idea how to do that! I have an Android app that makes txt files and can open it inside app

Answer (score 0):

@h8moss i have Android app made with flutter! I found that i can do that with file extension in androidmanifest like this:

```
<data android:scheme="file" />
<data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
```

But the problem is how i receive file location or data when i choose my app as default app to open txt file when i tap on file